# Output to Excel using ExcelLibrary in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, outputstream, excellibrary

The following code outputs to a csv file using controller.file. I want to change it to input to an excel sheet (.xls) instead of a csv file. I a using this library from here to do this.. http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

as per this stackoverflow post.. [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Edit:

```
foreach (var value in valueDataList)

    {
        var value1 = xxxxxxx    // this value is set here based on a query.. 
        int value2 = xxxxxxxx   // this value is set here based on a query.. 

        byte[] content;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())  
           {
              using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                  writer.WriteLine("ValueHeading1   " + " ValueHeading2");
                  writer.WriteLine(value1 + "              " + value2);                         
                }
                  content = ms.ToArray();
                  return File(content, "text/csv", "demo.csv");
            //ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelTest.xls", content);

           }
    }
```

How can I modify my existing code to putput to excel using this library. The last commented line in the code does not work because it expects 'content' to be a dataset and not a byte.. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Excel()
{
    DataSet ds = ...
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())  
    {
        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(ms, ds)
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "demo.xls");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just edited the OP with modified code.. I forgot about the streamwriter part of the code.. thanks for your help

Comment: @ZVenue, I absolutely don't see how your modified code has anything to do with the excellibrary. In order to use it you need to build a DataSet and pass it to the CreateWorkbook method as illustrated in the post you have linked to. You seem to have some existing code that generates a CSV file. You will have to modify it. Read the documentation of the product you are using. It will help you in this task.

Comment: basically I need to change how I write the output.. to a dataset from a stream.

Comment: @ZVenue, I don't see what your question has to do with ASP.NET MVC in fact?

Comment: I changed the writer to dataset and modified the code accordingly.. its working great. thank you